# Digitally signing PDF's using certificate in my webpage

Tags: pdf, digital-certificate

I have my own webpage www.kasperikoski.fi that is, the way I see it, trusted, and I would like to have the ability to digitally sign PDF-documents by using some kind of sertificate that is put into my webpage so that people really know that it is me signing all these documents.

At first I thought that maybe I could share "public key" at the bottom of my webpage, but then I heard something about OpenSSL. Could that be used in my needs?

How would you carry out this one so that I could use the PDF's integrated "sign digitally"-option?

Comment: why sign at the webpage level? just sign it in Acrobat when you produce the pdf.

Comment: Yes, but then again everyone could sign it using my name. Just put there "John Doe" and password ABC123. Another problem occures, when I sign documents and later I want to say, that "this wasn't me signing". The public key (or some other applicable) must be shared with eveyone for easy check-up. EDIT: I could also appeal, that "I just entereb my password 'ABC123', but it ain't working :3"

Comment: Use a certificate (and its associated private key) which you provide e.g. via your Web site.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that I read your question right, you want to let your web site visitors a way to download some documents, which are created or maintained by your web site, and you want those documents to be digitally signed.

If the document is pre-created, it's possible to sign it during creation (either with the tool that generates them, or create a separate piece of code for signing). If the documents are generated on-the-fly, then your web site should include signing capabilities.

To perform signing you need a certificate with a private key. But not every certificate would work. The certificate you need should be suitable for data signing, rather than just for SSL/TLS. You can try to obtain the certificate for your site from some CA and then use it for signing the documents. Whether the users' software would accept such certificates depends on how Key Usage and Extended Key Usage properties (extensions) of the certificate are put by the CA. Another option would be to create a self-signed certificate.

In case of a self-signed certificate you would want to place the certificate itself (without a private key) to your web site for the users to download and install. This is needed for validation of the signature in your signed documents. No need to say, that you don't put the private key to download, neither you provide it to your users by any other means. It's kept only on the server (and preferably secured to make stealing it harder for the possible attacker).

The technologies / components / tools to use in these scenarios depend on which of the above options you need.